# Why is this simple if statement failing with "command not found"?

Tags: bash

I have this simple bash script called `get-volume.sh`:

```
mutedStatus=`amixer -c 0 -D pulse get Master | tail -n 1 | grep -c '\[on\]'`

echo $mutedStatus

if "$mutedStatus" -eq 0; then
    echo 'x'
else
    echo `amixer get Master | awk -F'[]%[]' '/%/ {if ($7 == "off") { print "MM" } else { print $2 }}' | head -n 1`
fi

exit 0
```

It should

1. populate the `mutedStatus` variable with 1 if unmuted and 0 if muted
2. if muted, echo 'x', else echo the volume
3. exit

But when I run the script with `bash get-volume.sh` I get this irritating message:

```
1
get-volume.sh: line 7: 1: command not found
100
```

why is it giving that error?

It seems to be trying to execute my variable, which is where `1:` comes from, as when I mute my system the message changes to

```
get-volume.sh: line 7: 0: command not found
```

Comment: I think it's just a simple syntax error.  See https://acloudguru.com/blog/engineering/conditions-in-bash-scripting-if-statements

Comment: Looks like you figured it it out.  BTW the command at line 3 is invoked immediately at line 3, not when the variable is referenced as you seemed to indicate.

Comment: `-eq` is not a *shell* operator; it's an argument to be interpreted by the `test` command. You are literally trying to run a command named `1` with arguments `-eq` and `0`.

Comment: The condition in a shell `if` statement is a *command*, not an expression. The condition is true if the command succeeds, false if it fails. `[` is a special (often built-in) command that evaluates an expression.

Comment: BTW `#!.bin/bash` should be: `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: @KeithThompson. `[` is a builtin command in `bash`

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to write the if statement like this

```
...
if [ "$mutedStatus" -eq 0 ] ; then
...
```

Notice the space after `[` and before `]` - without this the command fails with

> get-volume.sh: line 7: [1: command not found

Comment: Other ways of writing the `if` statement include `if test "$mutedStatus" -eq 0`, `if [[ "$mutedStatus" -eq 0 ]]`, `if (( mutedStatus == 0 ))` , and `if let "mutedStatus == 0"` and many more.   However for portability, one such use the Posixly correct war, i.e.  `if [ "$mutedStatus" -eq 0 ]`